# "could not find com_facebook_android.apk error" when running Android project

Tags: java, android, facebook-android-sdk

I've installed the Facebook API for Android in Eclipse, and imported the project into my Android project.  My program builds perfectly fine, but when I try to run it I get

> Could not find com_facebook_android.apk!

in the build window, and when the program actually tries to import any of the Facebook API classes it blows up with a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.android.Facebook`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check out referencing libraries instructions here:
   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html
2. Make sure you have the latest versions of ADT.
3. Try to clean your project in eclipse.

Hope this helps

Comment: Removing and readding the facebook project to Eclipse seems to have fixed the problem

Answer (score 5):

Probably you added the reference to the Java project in the "Java Build Path" but it's the wrong place.

From the Android guide:

**To add a reference to a library project, follow these steps:**

- In the Package Explorer, right-click the dependent project and select Properties.
- In the Properties window, select the "Android" properties group at left and locate the Library properties at right.
- Click Add to open the Project Selection dialog.
- From the list of available library projects, select a project and click OK.
- When the dialog closes, click Apply in the Properties window.
- Click OK to close the Properties window

This resolved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

In my case helped, not to have in the referenced projects checked **`Is Library`**

(Project Properties > Android)

[image: sample image with "Is Library" unchecked]

Answer (score 1):

I am also having issues with this error and have noted that if I run eclipse as root then the error disappears. This makes me think it is a permissions issue

So to help:

On the com Facebook android project right click  > android tool > build and export

Then simply build the project into the bin folder of the Facebook project.

Problem solved

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. This was my resolution. I had to add android.jar as a reference.

[Android samples error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12830000/android-samples-error)

Answer (score 0):

If nothing works, try deleting the Facebook application for Android (if you have one installed on your phone). This worked for me.