# Could not find Facebook SDK.apk

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook-android-sdk

Hey I know this was asked before, but none of the solutions seem to help.

This is **NOT** a duplicate

I have used the Facebook SDK before on an earlier project, 
now I started a new one and I get this weird error.

- I **have** set a reference to the library
- I **have** set the Facebook SDK project as a library
- I **have** tried deleting it and re-adding it according to the [official documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/), and basically tried everything in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258394/could-not-find-com-facebook-android-apk-error-when-running-android-project).

Though I still get this error and can't find out why.

Worth to mention, when I tried to use the facebook class, it gave me an error with an option of "fix project", which I did and still didn't work, might be related?

Comment: Depending on the answer - we'll see if it is a duplicate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after alot of searches the only thing that worked for me is just creating a new project and copying all the files to it.

I tried avoiding it but that seems like the only thing that works =/

As there is no answer on this topic whatsoever, so if someone could find out a better solution - it will be very helpfull to the community

Comment: i am still facing this problem .

Answer (score 60):

This is common error. Just remove FacebookSDK project from Properties->Java Build Path->Projects . This project should be referenced from Properties->Android

For more information, see this answer: [Could not find Library.apk!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337673/could-not-find-library-apk)

Comment: @rottz This was answered much after I solved it, and it shouldn't be marked though it's a common solution as I didn't try it, and my solution (as bad as it is) did work.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.. I just want to ask whether did you import the Facebook SDK into Eclipse itself? Because I had did a project using Facebook and the thing is that besides referencing, the guide I followed actually instructed that the SDK must be imported into the Eclipse.

You might probably want to have a look at [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/). Else, the other way is just like what you did, copying all the files.

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the Facebook application for Android (if you have one installed on your phone). This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

i dont know how this is happened but it works :

first : i have added all facebook3.0 related sample + facebookSDk projects in one workspace .

second : i have run a sample project . in which i found a .jar file : 
androiddependencies->facebooksdk.jar (note this exact path )

third :

1.) i created my project .

2.) inside this i have removed errors by :- `FixProjectSetup (atLast position )`

3.) i have added `facebooksdk.jar` by right_clicking at `project->properties->android->by checking android 4.2 + reference the Facebooksdk -> done` .

now i am able to create and run programs easily .