# Facebook LoginButton could not be instatiated

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

In one of our apps some of the users experience a force close when launching the app. It turns out that there's something wrong with the Facebook button. I go to the designer and I see a gray rectangle in place of the desired button with the error:

> Rendering problems
>       The following classes could not be instatiated:
>       - com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
>   Tip: User View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code data when shown in the IDE
>
> Exception Details
>       java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: com_facebook_login_view_com_facebook_confirm_logout
>           at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.parseLoginButtonAttributes(LoginButton.java:591)
>           at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.configureButton(LoginButton.java:551)
>           at com.facebook.FacebookButtonBase.(FacebookButtonBase.java:66)
>           at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.(LoginButton.java:200)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
>           at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:437)
>           at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:154)
>           at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:93)
>           at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:190)
>           at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:214)
>           at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:142)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:806)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:782)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
>           at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:413)
>           at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:321)
>           at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
>           at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:511)
>           at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:499)
>           at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:888)
>           at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:499)
>           at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:72)
>           at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:611)
>           at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:608)
>           at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:363)
>           at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:608)
>           at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:630)
>           at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$6.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:480)
>           at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
>           at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
>           at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
>           at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
>           at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
>           at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
>           at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
>           at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:351)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Though this seems to be an IDE problem, the stacktraces I get from the users are the same:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.yolify.android/com.yolify.android.Activity_Splash}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.setBackgroundResource(int)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2802)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2867)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:181)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1476)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6134)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.setBackgroundResource(int)' on a null object reference
    at com.yolify.android.Activity_Splash.onCreate(Activity_Splash.java:214)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6374)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2746)
    ... 10 more
```

**Activity**

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        tracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {

            @Override
            protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(com.facebook.AccessToken oldAccessToken, com.facebook.AccessToken currentAccessToken) {

            }
        };
        tracker.startTracking();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        btn_fblogin = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        btn_fblogin.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_facebook_selector);
        btn_fblogin.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0); 
        btn_fblogin.setReadPermissions(PERMISSIONS);
        btn_fblogin.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, mCallback);


        btn_fblogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(CheckNetwork.isInternetAvailable(Activity_Splash.this)) {
                    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(Activity_Splash.this, PERMISSIONS);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please check your internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        ...

    }
```

It's like the Facebook button doesn't exist on their phones. This is a normal Activity. Facebook sdk is added as a dependency (.aar file, not gradle). All Facebook related imports are fine. Min SDK is 15, errors are coming from Android version 4.1 to 5.0.
What's wrong?

Comment: `In one of our apps some of the users experience a force close when launching the app.` Do you have a stack trace of that.
This seems to be an error from the IDE.

Comment: Added the stack trace and added the Activity code, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in

```
btn_fblogin.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_facebook_selector);
```

`btn_fblogin` is null, you have to make sure that id `@+id/login_button` exists in `activity_splash.xml`.

**EDIT:**
If you have CustomView in `activity_splash.xml` then try this --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/30785533/1008278

Comment: Fantastic idea, and how am I supposed to do that? I can check if it's null then make it invisible.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this before, i solved by using my own button that calls the click of the loginbuton (facebook) btn_fblogin.callOnClick();

//the rendering problem is because of this two lines that youset at runningtime
   btn_fblogin.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_facebook_selector);
   btn_fblogin.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);