# The SDK has not been initialized, make sure to call FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize() first

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have this error when implementing the Facebook SDK and i [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490399/error-inflating-class-com-facebook-widget-loginbutton) - [many of the](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29739958/1874460) - [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33733713/1874460) but none of then worked. This is what i have:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_name_layout);

LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {

            }
        });

     @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
```

Graddle:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.8.0'
```

Manifest:

```
 <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Layout button:

```
<LinearLayout

    xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/fb_login_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        ></com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton>
</LinearLayout>
```

Can someone point me out what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

The docs have you set it in the Application class now:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // Initialize the SDK before executing any other operations,
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
    }
}
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/

Comment: It's deprecated, and yet you get an error saying "You must call FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize() first".  lol good lord Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to use maveen() and both dependencies(***here you forget to add annotation dependencies***) of Facebook Audience Network, After this you your all problem will be solved.

> Do not implement helper class , it is deprecated.

In Android Studio, make sure that mavenCentral() or jcenter() is included in your project's list of repositories. Repositories are defined in your project's module-level build.gradle file.

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
```

Next, add the following implementation dependencies (check latest sdk- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/guides/adding-sdk/android ) to your project's list of dependencies. Dependencies are also defined in your project's module-level build.gradle file. Note that annotation support is required by the Audience Network SDK.

```
dependencies { 
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.+'
}
```

After at all do not implement helper classs. Replace it to latest method, call `AudienceNetworkAds.initialize(this)` in `onCreate`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AudienceNetworkAds.initialize(this);
}
```

Thanks
Happy Coding :)